# Can someone explain to a calculus student what "dual space is the space of linear functions" mean?

Tags: calculus, functions, vector-spaces, definition

I ran across this phrase today in a post and I am slightly confused.

From my understanding, the dual space is the space of functions that sends a vector to a real number.

There are two confusions:

1. my understanding is that a function sends a number to a real number, when I write $f(4) = 5$, I am not sending a vector to a number
2. functions are already vectors that satisfies all axioms of the vector space $V$, why would be also belong in the dual space of the vector space $V^*$?
3. what does "linear function" mean in this case? Why is the dual space not the space of non-linear functions such as $f(x) = sin(x)$

Sorry if my questions seem silly!

Comment: You are relying on too narrow a definition of *function.*  A function $f:A \to B$ is a type of *relation* between two sets $A$ (the domain, a.k.a. source) and $B$ (the codomain, a.k.a. target).  Have a look:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Function_(mathematics)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fix a vector space $V$, finite-dimensional, say. The dual space is defined by $$V^\ast = \{ f: V \to \Bbb R \mid f \text{ is linear}   \}.$$

> my understanding is that a function sends a number to a real number, when I write $f(4)=5$, I am not sending a vector to a number

If $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is linear, and you're looking the first $\Bbb R$ as the vector field, and the second $\Bbb R$ as the underlying field, then $f \in \Bbb R^\ast$. You're applying $f$ in a vector: $4$ (an element of the first $\Bbb R$).

> functions are already vectors that satisfies all axioms of the vector space $V$, why would be also belong in the dual space of the vector space $V^∗$?

**Vectors** are elements of a **vector space**. So functions are vectors, because they're elements of a vector space (the dual space of the initial space). Functions don't necessarily verify the axioms for $V$. They will do so for $V^\ast$, with the operations defined pointwise.

> what does "linear function" mean in this case? Why is the dual space not the space of non-linear functions such as $f(x)=\sin(x)$

Given $V,W$ vector spaces over the same field, say, $\Bbb R$, we say that $T: V \to W$ is linear if $T(x+\lambda y) = T(x)+\lambda T(y)$ for all $x,y \in V$ and for all $\lambda \in \Bbb R$. The dual space only consider the linear functions by definition, since they're have special properties and applications (such as *linear* approximations, derivatives, etc), and are easier to work with than arbitrary functions.

Comment: So what situations that I may encounter in introductory calculus would it be appropriate to write $f \in \mathbb{R}$ instead of $f \in \mathbb{R}^*$? Should you always write $f \in \mathbb{R}^*$ for all functions defined on $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: Say if I had $f(x) = sin(x)$, should I write $f \in \mathbb{R}$ instead of $f \in \mathbb{R}^*$? What about $f(x) = 2*x$ or some other linear functions?

Comment: Don't write $f \in \Bbb R$ unless $f$ is **real number**. In a calculus context, rarely you'll deal with linear functions in the sense that I've defined above. And writing $f \in \Bbb R^*$ means that $f: \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ is *linear*. Sure, you can write it, if you ever come across it..

Comment: Ok so for linear functions I may write $f \in \mathbb{R}^*$, but what about nonlinear functions? Is there some space for nonlinear functions?

Comment: Perhaps you're confusing the function $f$ with it's value in a point, $f(x)$. They are not the same thing. If you have $f: A \subset \Bbb R \to \Bbb R$, linear or not, you can safely write $f(x) \in \Bbb R$, always. Be careful when dealing with $f$ only.

Comment: You can define ${\scr C}^0(\Bbb R)$ the set of all continuous functions from $\Bbb R$ to $\Bbb R$. This way an appropriate notation is $f \in {\scr C}^0(\Bbb R)$.

Comment: Thanks! You are better at explaining than Gauss himself

Comment: Don't overdo it :P
Glad I could help, though